# How do I represent multiple DTOs for a domain object in .NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, automapper, dto

I'm writing a set of REST services and have come upon a problem that I'm sure has an appropriate solution/pattern that's just eluding me.

For instance /api/People/1 will return a serialized representation of PersonDto (which is a pared down representation of the Person domain object created by Entity Framework.  I'm using AutoMapper to hydrate PersonDto.

However a second controller (say, /api/Classes/) is going to return different complex object, which may contain one or more Persons, however I want to represent each person in a different way than simply using an existing PersonDto (e.g. I might require more or less fields).

Do I need to define a ClassPersonDto?  I'm not sure what the "proper" thing is to do here.

Comment: Online resources that may be helpful: 
This first link is for creating RESTful services with WCF (not WebAPI), but the first half of the article is general for all web services and discusses your question. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx
And here's the MS Web API portal: 
http://www.asp.net/web-api

Answer (score 0):

If the model of "person" being passed back in "Classes" is different then the "PersonDto" model, then yes, create a different model. You don't need to, but it's almost always better to keep your classes, including entities, as specific as possible.

Comment: It sounds like you're conclusion is the same as mine.  To give some more detail to the situation, I'm thinking of a case where sending all the information about a Person is not allowed in the second service (say some private information like a social security number or something).